# Binding selected items to list<t> in viewmodel

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, data-binding

I have the following property in my view model:

```
public List<Departments> DepartmentList
{
    get { return NewTechnician.departmentList; }
    set
    {
        NewTechnician.departmentList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DepartmentList");
    }
}
```

I have a DataGrid that is bound to this list, with the following values

```
public class Departments
{
    public int departmentId { get; set; }
    public string departmentDescription { get; set; }
    public int requestAccess { get; set; }
    public int queueAccess { get; set; }
    public int departmentStatus { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
}
```

I need to be able to insert the departmentid from the selected rows into my database.  How can i bind the values for departmentID based on the selected rows in either the existing list or a new list.  (the selection mode is set to Extended)

```
foreach (Departments department in createNewTech.selectedDepartments)
{
    if (department.selected == true)
    {
        sql = @"insert into Tech_Department_Link Values(@techId,@DepartmentId)";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TechID", createNewTech.newTech.techID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", department.departmentId);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this working? are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should better not insert the ModelItems in Plain to your Datagrid. Better you should create a ObservableCollection with the Generic Type of a DepartmentViewModel, which holds the Department and the Properties like your "IsSelected", which isn't really a model property but a helper Property for your Logic and View.

Then you can go into your Xaml where your Datagrid is, and do the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DepartmentViewModels}">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Your Viewmodel for all Departments holds a Property like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<DepartmentViewModel> DepartmentViewModels
```

Then your can get all ids of the Selected Departments via

```
var ids = (from dpvm in this.DepartmentViewModels
            where dpvm.IsSelected
            select dpvm.Id).ToList();
```

**Edit:**
If you want to stay with your Model directly in the List, than the first snipped must be the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DepartmentList}">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding selected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response.  I'm having some trouble implimenting though.

I have a Department Model and in my ViewModel a list of Departments.  My datagrid is currently bound to that list.  I may be doing this very wrong , but i am still unclear how the selection in the datagrid updates that record in the list to indicate that it has been selected.

Comment: so currently your Model (Department) which is your datacontext in every datagrid row has a property "selected". It is set via the code of the first snipped in my answer. But replace the Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" against Value="{Binding selected, Mode=TwoWay}" (with lowercase 'selected')

Comment: thanks a bunch Frerk this was very helpful. I ended up using check box columns to update two separate values and then send that info back to the database.